# Convert values to vector from specific row

Tags: r

I have a dataframe df, when I have converted to vectors. But is there a way to start from specific columns

```
> asd <- data.frame(a = c("A","B","C","D"), b = c(1,2,3,4))
> asd$b <- as.character(asd$b)
> paste0("(",asd$a, asd$b,")")
[1] "(A1)" "(B2)" "(C3)" "(D4)"
```

Expected output (Only 2 and 3 rows)

```
[1] "(B2)" "(C3)"
```

Comment: Which specific column you want to start from?

Answer (score 3):

One approach would be to use `[` to subset:

```
paste0("(",asd[2:3,"a"], asd[2:3,"b"],")")
#[1] "(B2)" "(C3)"
```

The `[` operator when applied to `data.frame`s has two arguments, `i`, and `j`.

The `i` argument specifies rows and the `j` argument specifies columns. You can use a character vector in `j` to specify columns, but you can also use integers:

```
paste0("(",asd[2:3,1], asd[2:3,2],")")
#[1] "(B2)" "(C3)"
```

In addition to using integers in `i` you can also use a logical vector:

```
asd$a %in% c("B","C")
#[1] FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE

paste0("(",asd[asd$a %in% c("B","C"),1], asd[asd$a %in% c("B","C"),2],")")
#[1] "(B2)" "(C3)"
```

Please see `help(Extract)` for more.